# TikZ/pgf: How to draw edges that start and end at the same node when using the `graphdrawing` library?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have borrowed [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/) from http://www.texample.net/.

[image]

The graph exhibits a characteristic that I do not know how to reproduce using the `graphdrawing` library: its nodes have edges that start and end at the same node. How would this be done when using the `graphdrawing` library?

Here's what I have tried so far. I attempted to force the edge length to be a certain amount, so that the algorithm would have to draw a edge with that length, but then also loop it back. It seems that this command does not *force* the edge to be a certain length, and thus produces a nonsense result.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}

\begin{document}


    \tikz [rounded corners]
        \graph [spring layout]
        {
            a ->
            {
                b ->[length=3] b
            }
        };

\end{document}
```

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing an example [here](http://www.fsmint.uni-luebeck.de/sites/www.fscs.uni-luebeck.de/files/Vortrag_Graphdrawing_15062011.pdf), which showed how `[bend right]` could be used with edges in `graphdrawing`, I tried `[loop right]` similar to what the example I first presented does. Lo and behold, it works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}

\begin{document}


    \tikz [rounded corners]
        \graph [spring layout]
        {
            a ->
            {
                b ->[loop right] b
            }
        };

\end{document}
```

[image]